# Bug: Lumen using local time while save timestamp record

Tags: laravel, lumen

In Lumen 5.3, I use default timezone (UTC), and when I using:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

It show the UTC timezone

but when I save a new record with timestamps, it save my local time zone.

Example: My timezone is +07:00, and the local time is 11h00.
When using: `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`, it is show `2018-12-27 04:00:00`, but when I save new record, the created_at field is `2018-12-27 11:00:00`. The value I want to save is: `2018-12-27 04:00:00`

How can I fix it, please help me. thank you.

Comment: Your app timezone needs to be 'UTC': `$yourmodel->created_at = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate(2018, 1, 1, 'America/Toronto');` OR You can set your app time zone by configuring app.php file in config folder: `'timezone' => 'America/Toronto'`

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this in config/app.php
change your timezone

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

> Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
>   will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
>   ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.

find php timezones here :
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: There is no config/app.php by default in lumen. Adding one doesn't appear to change it. Can you elaborate?